# MacBook Pro 12,1 Trackpad Issues

Tags: drivers, mac, macbook-pro

I am a little lost here. I have removed `xserver-xorg-inputs-synaptics` and installed `xserver-xorg-inputs-mtrack` for my MBP trackpad, however I can't get the driver to be loaded because for some reason my trackpad is being detected as a "pointer" as evident from these lines on the xorg startup log:

```
[     5.645] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (/dev/input/event8)
[     5.645] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[     5.645] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad'
```

This is also verified by changing `MatchIsTouchpad "on"` to `MatchIsPointer "on"` in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` successfully loading the driver (although this doesn't actually help because then I can't move it around)

Other relevant info:

- MacbookPro 12,1
- Ubuntu 15.04
- kernel 3.19.0-25-generic

Contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Identifier      "Touchpads"
    Driver          "mtrack"
    Option          "Sensitivity" "0.55"
    Option          "FingerHigh" "12"
    Option          "FingerLow" "1"
    Option          "IgnoreThumb" "true"
    Option          "IgnorePalm" "true"
    Option          "TapButton1" "1"
    Option          "TapButton2" "3"
    Option          "TapButton3" "0"
    Option          "TapButton4" "0"
    Option          "ClickFinger1" "1"
    Option          "ClickFinger2" "3"
    Option          "ClickFinger3" "3"
    Option          "ButtonMoveEmulate" "false"
    Option          "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
    Option          "ClickTime" "25"
    Option          "BottomEdge" "25"
    Option          "SwipeLeftButton" "8"
    Option          "SwipeRightButton" "9"
    Option          "SwipeUpButton" "0"
    Option          "SwipeDownButton" "0"
    Option          "ScrollDistance" "75"
EndSection
```

All relevant `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` output

```
[     5.644] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[     5.644] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     5.644] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.644] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.644] (**) Option "xkb_options" "ctrl:nocaps"
[     5.645] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (/dev/input/event8)
[     5.645] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[     5.645] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad'
[     5.645] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: always reports core events
[     5.645] (**) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[     5.700] (--) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Vendor 0x5ac Product 0x273
[     5.700] (--) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[     5.700] (--) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Found relative axes
[     5.700] (--) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Found x and y relative axes
[     5.700] (II) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: Configuring as mouse
[     5.700] (**) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[     5.700] (**) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[     5.700] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/0003:05AC:0273.0006/input/input8/event8"
[     5.700] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad" (type: MOUSE, id 14)
[     5.700] (II) evdev: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: initialized for relative axes.
[     5.700] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     5.700] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     5.700] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     5.700] (**) Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     5.700] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (/dev/input/mouse2)
```

and relevant `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` output

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=05ac Product=0273 Version=0110
N: Name="Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:05AC:0273.0005/input/input7
U: Uniq=D3H5265H171GHJGAN4PS
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000010007 ff9f217ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=05ac Product=0273 Version=0110
N: Name="Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/0003:05AC:0273.0006/input/input8
U: Uniq=D3H5265H171GHJGAN4PS
H: Handlers=mouse2 event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: MSC=10
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, although I do not have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` at all.

Comment: @KouberSaparev hey this git repo contains a kernel patch that fixes this problem: https://github.com/SicVolo/hid-apple-3.19 I don't remember where I found it though.  You'll need to add this `keycode 94 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde` to `$HOME/.Xmodmap` as well to fix the ~` key if you have the same version as me. `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` isn't there by default now, I made that one.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded the kernel to 4.2 yesterday, so the trackpad works now, at least the scrolling part: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2270831&page=6#post13366032